# How to download source code of a NON FLEX app-engine application

Tags: google-app-engine

Problem:

I have a non-flex App Engine application that I no longer have access to the source code for. I forgot to remove the 15-day deletion policy from the bucket, so the code has been deleted.

Question:

Is there anything I can do to recover the source code? How is the application still running if I cannot find the source code anywhere?

Comment: Pull the docker image and run it. It's stored under /workspace.

Comment: @bob, a non-flex app doesnt have a docker image avaiable on gcp

Comment: Every deployment will go through Cloud Build to build the container. Check your GAE region. There will be an output image.